# Problem playing multiple files in MPlayer OSX Extended

Tags: macos, video, osx-snow-leopard, playback, mplayer

I have certain video files setup to be opened by MPlayer OSX Extended by default. If I click on one of these files, and the video finishes playing, then when I click on another file, it won't play. I have to quit MPlayer in order to play another file.